# Luhn Algorithm Logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, credit-card, luhn

I am currently going through Codecademy's Full Stack Engineer course, up until now I have been perfectly fine with it, discovering new things, working out problems on my own, but this is a serious roadblock in my progression as I just can't seem to identify the problem with this logic. I don't mean to question Luhn's algorithm but seriously I need some clarification on this...

So my problem is, that the algorithm is returning all my arrays as valid, my code is below (arrays provided by codecademy):

```
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];
```

And my function implementing the algorithm:

```
const validateCred = arr => {

    let checkSum = 0;
    let ifEvenDouble = 0;
    arr.push(checkSum);

    //Iterate through array, double what is needed

    for(let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
      console.log(ifEvenDouble);

      //If ifEvenDouble is even, we are at the 'other' cell

        if((ifEvenDouble % 2) === 0){
          let doubled = arr[i] * 2;

          //If doubled digit is greater than 9, store sum of individual digits
          //Convert the doubled number to a string then extract each member and convert back to number for calculation, add to checkSum and skip to next iteration, otherwise, add arr[i]

          let newDigit = 0;
          if(doubled > 9){
            newDigit = Number(doubled.toString()[0]) + Number(doubled.toString()[1]);
            //Add doubled & split digit to total and continue the loop
            checkSum += newDigit;
            ifEvenDouble++;
            continue;
          }
          //Add doubled digit less than 9 to total and continue the loop
          checkSum += doubled;
          ifEvenDouble++;
          continue;
        }

        //Add current array member to total
        checkSum += arr[i];
        ifEvenDouble++;

    }//End for loop

    console.log(checkSum);
    const checkDigit = (checkSum * 9) % 10;
    const totalSum = checkDigit + checkSum;

    if(totalSum % 10 === 0){
      console.log('Valid');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid');
      return false;
    }
};

validateCred(invalid1); // -> Output: Valid
```

From my understanding, my totalSum is **always** going to be a multiple of 10, if I'm subtracting my unit digit from 10, adding it to my checkSum is **always** going to give me a multiple of 10. Am I wrong?

Edit: I have been attempting to debug this already but the more I do the further away from the core algorithm I stray.

Edit(2): So thanks to the guys below, I think my issue was generating my own check digit as opposed to using one already provided? My confusion is that from reading the wikipedia page on this, it says:

'Example for computing check digit:
Assume an example of an account number "7992739871" that will have a check digit added, making it of the form 7992739871x'

And then they proceeded to do all their calculations with the numbers besides x, i think this is the main confusion now.

Comment: What's the actual problem? Any errors? What have you tried so far to solve/debug this on your own?

Comment: My issue is that the supposedly invalid cc numbers are returning valid according to this algorithm. I have attempted to debug this for the last 3 hours but I end up straying away from the core algorithm and the point is to implement it.

Comment: Find one that returns the wrong result, step through the rounds of your loop and check the values where and when it goes wrong.

Comment: You're double counting the doubled and original digit arn't you? Thats a mistake. Also, no need to split and combine the ones >9 just subtract 9. eg 8+4 = 12. Then 1+2 =3 but 12-9 would give same result

Comment: I have tested each array individually, and have even done each of them on paper just to make sure, and even on paper they are returning a mod of 0. I'd like to think I implemented the algorithm wrong, but I've even had my code checked to ensure I was implementing all steps

Comment: @Jamiec sorry where do you see the double counting? Also I was aware I would just subtract by 9, but for coding practice I used type conversion :)

Comment: Why do you change the content of `arr` (`arr.push(checkSum)`? That's messing with your index in the loop.

Comment: I got so warped up in looking for the issue I followed the wikipeda page line for line, appending what was to be the checksum to the end of the array before calculating, not that it made a difference anyway as I just set the for loop to start at arr.length - 2 which is the second last array member (same as me not pushing at all and starting from arr.length - 1)

Comment: _"to start at arr.length - 2 which is the second last array member"_ - Which would be correct because you have to skip the right-most (last) element, which is at index `array.length - 1` making the element at `array.length - 2` the first element to work with. But with adding the checksum you messed with these numbers.

Comment: @Andreas that IS what I thought, but there are `continue`'s in there. Makes it hard to follow. As my answer says, hugely over complicated implementation  for something so simple.

Comment: @Andreas I'm sorry I'm just not understanding what you mean, how am i messing up my numbers? The loop still starts and ends where intended?

Comment: @Jamiec I appreciate your post below, I would also like to gain an understanding rather than just looking at a simplified version, please see my comment below that post thank you

Comment: I'll try to update it with more places you went wrong, but it was mainly around the check digit

Comment: _"And then they proceeded to do all their calculations with the numbers besides x"_ - Not really. `x` is just a place holder for the last digit of the example numbers, which is the only digit that is different. The _"Example for computing check digit"_ section just explains how that check digit is calculated and therefor why the account number ending with `3` is the only valid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is unnecessarily complicated. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) describes it succinctly, just implement the 3 steps

> 1. From the rightmost digit (excluding the check digit) and moving left, double the value of every second digit. The check digit is neither doubled nor included in this calculation; the first digit doubled is the digit located immediately left of the check digit. If the result of this doubling operation is greater than 9 (e.g., 8 × 2 = 16), then add the digits of the result (e.g., 16: 1 + 6 = 7, 18: 1 + 8 = 9) or, equivalently, subtract 9 from the result (e.g., 16: 16 − 9 = 7, 18: 18 − 9 = 9).
> 2. Take the sum of all the digits (including the check digit).
> 3. If the total modulo 10 is equal to 0 (if the total ends in zero) then the number is valid according to the Luhn formula; otherwise it is not valid.

I also think you misunderstood what the check digit is. You appeared to be appending it to the array as `0`, and trying to calculate it at the end. It's already there in the number - it's the final digit.

```js
const validateCred = arr => {

   let doubleIt = true;
   let sum = 0;
   // From the rightmost digit excluding check digit...
   for(let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
        
        if(doubleIt){
          let doubled = arr[i] * 2;
         
          if(doubled > 9){
            doubled -= 9
          }
          sum += doubled
        }
        else {
          sum += arr[i]
        }
        doubleIt = !doubleIt;

    }

    // Add the check digit to the sum
    sum += arr[arr.length-1];

    // If sum is divisible by 10 it is valid
    if(sum % 10 === 0){
      console.log('Valid');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid');
      return false;
    }
};

const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
validateCred(invalid1);
validateCred(valid1);
```

The places you went wrong were mainly around the use of the check digit. You appeared to be calculating it whereas its already there as just the final element in the array. The below snippet is a lot closer to your original, just without the calculation of check digit.

```js
const validateCred = arr => {

    let ifEvenDouble = 0;
   let checkSum=0
    //Iterate through array, double what is needed

    for(let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){

      //If ifEvenDouble is even, we are at the 'other' cell

        if((ifEvenDouble % 2) === 0){
          let doubled = arr[i] * 2;

          //If doubled digit is greater than 9, store sum of individual digits
          //Convert the doubled number to a string then extract each member and convert back to number for calculation, add to checkSum and skip to next iteration, otherwise, add arr[i]

          let newDigit = 0;
          if(doubled > 9){
            newDigit = Number(doubled.toString()[0]) + Number(doubled.toString()[1]);
            //Add doubled & split digit to total and continue the loop
            checkSum += newDigit;
            ifEvenDouble++;
            continue;
          }
          //Add doubled digit less than 9 to total and continue the loop
          checkSum += doubled;
          ifEvenDouble++;
          continue;
        }

        //Add current array member to total
        checkSum += arr[i];
        ifEvenDouble++;

    }//End for loop

    const checkDigit = arr[arr.length-1]
    const totalSum = checkDigit + checkSum;

    if(totalSum % 10 === 0){
      console.log('Valid');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid');
      return false;
    }
};


const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
validateCred(invalid1);
validateCred(valid1);
```

Comment: This looks really simple however I'd like to understand the changes fully rather than just using it, for learning purposes. I have a question, since you did not push the check digit onto the array, 1. why does the for loop start at the second to last digit, and 2. is arr[arr.length-1] not pointing to the last digit in the credit card number? I don't see anything pushed.

Comment: "why does the for loop start at the second to last digit" - because as I said in the answer, the check digit is already in the array. length-1 would therefore be the check digit and length-2 is the first number that needs doubling _the first digit doubled is the digit located immediately left of the check digit_.  "is arr[arr.length-1] not pointing to the last digit in the credit card number? I don't see anything pushed" - yes its pointing to the check digit which must be included in the sum _Take the sum of all the digits (including the check digit)._

Comment: There is never any reason to push anything into the array. The array represents an actual card number. If you look at your credit/debit card the last number in the long card number is the check digit

Comment: I think I have a greater understanding of this now, so is my issue the fact that I thought I had to generate the check digit from the card number, but instead, the check digit is already in the provided arrays?

Comment: @jkn600 exactly! Just just skip over it for the purpose of doubling elements. Updated with a solution which more closely matches your original so hopefully you can see which specific parts you went wrong on.

Comment: Thank you so much! If you see my original post I have edited it with the wikipedia extract that might be to blame for this, did I really read it so wrong? haha

Comment: Thank you for the re-write, having seen your code before I am now going to challenge myself to simplify my logic until it is similar to what I saw before now that I've seen how much it can be simplified. Thanks! StackOverflow is a lot faster than I expected :)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was more about where you went wrong than about a better solution; the answer from Jamiec already covers that quite well.

However, with a dollop of array methods, we should be able to write a much simpler answer.

```js
// utility functions
const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
const last = (xs) => xs [xs .length - 1]

// helper function
const doubleDig = (d) => 2 * d > 9 ? 2 * d - 9 : 2 * d

// main function
const luhn = (ds) =>
  (sum ([... ds] .map (Number) .reverse () .slice(1) .map (
    (d, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? doubleDig (d) : d
  )) + Number (last (ds)))  % 10 == 0

// sample data
const batch = [
  /* Valid   */ [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8], [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9], [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6], [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5], [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6],
  /* Invalid */ [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5], [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3], [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4], [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5], [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4],
  /* Mystery */ [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4], [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9], [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3], [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3], [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3],
]

// demo
console.log (batch .map (luhn))

console .log (
  luhn ('4539677908016808'),
  luhn ('4532778771091795')
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This function works on the array of single-digit numbers supplied, but also on a string of digits, so that `luhn ('4539677908016808')` is equivalent to `luhn ([4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8])`.

First we ensure we are working with an array of numbers, with `[... ds] .map (Number)`.  Then we `.reverse` the array to make it easier to track even and odd positions without fiddling with the array length.  We `.slice` off the now-first element, which we will only need later as the check-digit.  Now we map over the results, doubling the even digits and casting out nines as necessary (using the helper function `doubleDig`), but keeping the odd digits intact.  We total the results using the helper `sum` and find the last digit using the helper `last`, convert it into a number and add it to that total.  We finish by taking the modulus base 10, and report whether that value is 0.

Those helper functions are useful, and I would almost always prefer to work with such, but each is called in only one place in our main function, which makes it easy to inline them if we want, and we could write a stand-alone version of this doing so:

```js
const luhn = (ds) =>
  ([...ds] .map (Number) .reverse () .slice(1) .map (
    (d, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? (2 * d > 9 ? 2 * d - 9 : 2 * d) : d
  ) .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0) + Number (ds [ds .length - 1])) % 10 == 0
```

I do not think this is an improvement.  While the original version is dense, it's also not hard to follow.  This one, especially where we inline the conditional expression (ternary) of `doubleDig` inside another ternary, seems pretty ugly.  Perhaps a more spacious layout would help.<sup>1</sup>  But `sum (...)` is definitely cleaner than `(...) .reduce ((a , b) => a + b, 0)` and `last` is cleaner than its alternative.  Overall, this is uninspiring.  But it's good to recognize as an alternative to the helper-function break-down above.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, a more spacious layout improves this a *lot*!

```
const luhn = (ds) =>
  ([...ds]
    .slice (0, -1)
    .reverse () 
    .map (Number) 
    .map ((d, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? (2 * d > 9 ? 2 * d - 9 : 2 * d) : d) 
    .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0) 
    + Number (ds [ds .length - 1])) 
    % 10 
    == 0
```

But even better is realizing that we don't have to treat the check-digit separately if we change the parity on which we're doing the digit-doubling routine.  That leaves us the much nicer

```
const luhn = ([...ds]) => (ds
  .reverse () 
  .map (Number) 
  .map ((d, i) => i % 2 == 1 ? (2 * d > 9 ? 2 * d - 9 : 2 * d) : d) 
  .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0) 
) % 10 == 0
```

... at which point the helper functions are, at most, nice to have.  This reads fine.

Comment: Thank you scott for this, I will be honest it is very confusing at first (you know when somethings looks so simple it becomes complicated?) But as with Jamiec's answer it is another solution I can work towards being able to write myself. Many thanks!