# Trying to do Luhns Algorithm in Javascript but my programming keeps looping indefinitely

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

As the title says I am trying to write luhns algorithm in Javascript and have it print out a valid card number and what type of card it is whether that be American Express, Mastercard, or Visa.

When ran all it does is continuously loop the alert box. What I want it to print is this is a valid card type and what brand of card it is in the Alert Box.

```js
function checkCreditCard() {
  var ccnum = document.getElementById("cardnum").value;
  var cardArray = [cardnum]
  var temp = ccnum;
  var checkerArray;
  if (cardType(ccnum) === "AmericanExpress") {
    checkerArray = [15];
    for (x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
      checkerArray[x] = ccnum % 10;
      ccnum = ccnum / 10;
    }
  } else {
    checkerArray = [16];
    for (x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
      checkerArray[x] = ccnum % 10;
      ccnum = ccnum / 10;
      if (ccnum == 0) {
        checkerArray[15] = -1;
        checkerArray[14] = -1;
        checkerArray[13] = -1;
      }
    }
  }
  var summing;
  for (x = 1; x < checkerArray.length; x = x + 2) {

    if (checkerArray[x] < 0) {
      return;
    }
    checkerArray[x] = checkerArray[x] * 2;
    if (checkerArray[x] >= 10) {
      summing = summing + checkerArray[x] % 10 + checkerArray[x] / 10
    } else {
      summing = summing + checkerArray[x];
    }
  }

  for (x = 0; x < checkerArray.length; x = x + 2) {

    if (checkerArray[x] < 0) {
      return;
    }
    summing = summing + checkerArray[x];

    if (summing == 20) {
      alert("This Card is Legit")
    } else {
      alert("This Card is Invalid")
    }
  }

  function cardType(ccnum) {

    var x = {
      Visa: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/,
      Mastercard: /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/,
      AmericanExpress: /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,
    }
    for (var l in x) {
      if (x[l].test(ccnum)) {
        return l;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cardnum" onkeyup="checkCreditCard()" />
<span id="valid">Enter a Number and Press Enter</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do Luhn's correctly, even after mplungjan's fixes. (My Mastercard fails, although I know it's legit.)  You might want to look at [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+luhn) for it.  I have a [concise one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175134/1243641) available.

Comment: where does `cardnum` originate in `cardArray = [cardnum]`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use let

Also let's move the alert OUTSIDE the loop

```js
function cardType(ccnum) {

  var x = {
    Visa: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/,
    Mastercard: /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/,
    AmericanExpress: /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,
  }
  for (var l in x) {
    if (x[l].test(ccnum)) {
      return l;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

document.getElementById("cardForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var ccnum = document.getElementById("cardnum").value;
  if (ccnum.length < 16) return
  var cardArray = [cardnum]
  var temp = ccnum;
  var checkerArray;
  if (cardType(ccnum) === "AmericanExpress") {
    checkerArray = [15];
    for (let x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
      checkerArray[x] = ccnum % 10;
      ccnum /= 10;
    }
  } else {
    checkerArray = [16];
    for (let x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
      checkerArray[x] = ccnum % 10;
      ccnum /= 10;
      if (ccnum == 0) {
        checkerArray[15] = -1;
        checkerArray[14] = -1;
        checkerArray[13] = -1;
      }
    }
  }
  var summing;
  for (let x = 1; x < checkerArray.length; x = x + 2) {
    checkerArray[x] *= 2;
    if (checkerArray[x] >= 10) {
      summing +=  checkerArray[x] % 10 + checkerArray[x] / 10
    } else {
      summing += checkerArray[x];
    }
  }

  for (let x = 0; x < checkerArray.length; x = x + 2) {
    summing += checkerArray[x];
  }
  if (summing == 20) {
    alert("This Card is Legit")
  } else {
    alert("This Card is Invalid")
  }

})
```

```html
<form id="cardForm">
<input type="tel" id="cardnum" maxlength="16" />
<span id="valid">Enter a Number and Press Enter</span>
</form>
```