# why it is returning only false? Luhn algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, luhn

What's wrong with my code? It should return true for this array. The invalid one should return false.
Please explain it to me because i'm just started with JS

```js
//arrays :
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];

const validateCred = Array => {
    let cardNum = 0
    let reverseArray = Array.reverse()
    for (let i = 0; i < reverseArray.length; i++){

        let newVar = reverseArray[i]

       if (i%2 !== 0){
        newVar = reverseArray[i] * 2
            if (newVar > 9){
                newVar = newVar[i] - 9;
                cardNum += newVar
            } else {
                cardNum += newVar
            }
       } else {
        cardNum += reverseArray[i]
       }
    }
    return(cardNum%10 === 0 ? true : false)
}
console.log(validateCred(valid1))
```

Comment: Really should not use `Array` as a variable name

Comment: okay i just found it out because i used the index[i]wrong!
VS Code literally signified me that the index behind "newVar[i] - 9" was misplaced and i guess JS could simply not read the property from it. I just deleted it and now the code works

Comment: @Pointy it is just for me, to better understand what i place where. But i changed Array to arr now in my code

Comment: The reason it's good to not use "Array" is that it is the global name of the Array constructor function. It is not an error to use it as your own variable name, but very strange things can happen.

Comment: A perfect opportunity to learn about debugging. This small program and the quite small failing example should be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out and noted in the comments, this is not going to go well when `newVar` is a number:

```js
newVar = newVar[i] - 9;
```

And as Pointy, um, *pointed out*, `Array` is a terrible name for a variable, shadowing an important constructor function.  More than that, there is a strong convention in JS that **I**nitialCapital variable names are reserved for constructor functions.  I would suggest a name that describes what it's for, not its type.  Perhaps `"creditCard"` would be useful, or, depending on your tolerance for short abbreviations, `"cc"`.

But there's another, more subtle, problem with this code.  It alters its input:

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
console .log (validateCred (valid1)) //=> true
console .log (valid1) //=> [8, 0, 8, 6, 1, 0, 8, 0, 9, 7, 7, 6, 9, 3, 5, 4]
```

In a real application, this could cause you all sorts of problems, and maybe far away from this section, always frustrating.

It's easy enough to fix.  Just clone the array before reversing it.  There are many ways to do it (using `myVariable.slice()` or `myVariable.concat()`, for instance.)  My preference these days is to spread it into a new array: `[...myVariable]`.

---

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175134) to another Luhn's Algorithm question, I developed what I think of as an elegant version of this algorithm.  If you're new to JS, this may use some features you're not familiar with, but I find it clear and useful.  This is a slightly improved version:

```js
const luhn = (ds) => (
  [...ds]
    .filter(d => /^\d$/ .test (d))
    .reverse () 
    .map (Number) 
    .map ((d, i) => i % 2 == 1 ? (2 * d > 9 ? 2 * d - 9 : 2 * d) : d) 
    .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0) 
) % 10 == 0
```

It's the same algorithm, just expressed a little more concisely.  Between the spreading of the initial value and the `filter` call (removing non-digits), it allows us to pass various input formats:

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = "4539677908016808"
const valid3 = "4539-6779-0801-6808"
const valid4 = "4539 6779 0801 6808"
```

Comment: great post raising awareness of the lurking pains caused by mutation. also my first time hearing about Luhn's algorithm. convenient use of `filter` to clone the input :D

Comment: now please javascript give us functional `let` expressions... `let dd = 2 * d in dd < 10 ? dd : dd - 9`... **please**... 

Comment: or in the form of `where`, like `dd < 10 ? dd : dd - 9 where dd = 2, ...`. maybe we should make a proposal? ps have you ever tested if `x & 1` is faster than `x % 2 == 1`?

Comment: @Mulan: Yes, I would really love true `let` expressions.  I don't recognize that `where`?  Care to expand?  No, I haven't tested `x & 1` versus `x % 2 == 1`.  But I would rarely choose the former except for extremely performance-critical code, as `x % 2 == 1` is much more explicit.  Moreover, they have different behaviors on non-integers:  `Math.PI & 1 //=> 1`, but `Math.PI % 2 == 1 //=> false`.

Comment: @mulan: note that the input is already cloned via `[...ds]`.  This allows for input as a single string or an array of digits (or, I guess, as any Iterable of digits.)  The `filter` is to remove non-digit characters in an input such as `"4539-6779-0801-6808"`, although of course, it does also serve as an additional clone too.

Comment: I actually didn't see the `=> ([...ds]` (note typo) in the original. I see now that the spread is used to support other iterables like string types. I had a little typo in my `where` example, `dd < 10 ? dd : dd - 9 where dd = 2 * d, ...` would effectively be `<expr> where <bindings>`, allowing assignments to be used for a single expression. With bindings coming after the expression, it can offer a more declarative, top-down program like `doSomething(foo) == freeVar where doSomething = ..., foo = ...`. If I had it my way, JS would offer both.

Comment: Oh, I see, `where` is simply a different syntax for `let` bindings.  Then, yes, I have see it, at least in Haskell.  Yes, I would love to have these.  BTW, that's not a typo, just poor code layout; when I realized I'd forgotten the modulus check after I'd calculated the value, I lazily stuck the parentheses before and after the existing body.  It's fixed now.

Comment:  _mmph__ sorry! I really thought it was a typo. This is actually a perfect case for `where`. `checksum % 10 == 0 where checksum = [...ds].filter()...`! At any rate, you can probably keep the clean program and remove the strikeout one :D

Comment: It's gone.  And yes, `where` would be very nice here... and all over with the coding style I prefer: possibly even nicer than a true `let`.